# How to dump sql in shell

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp

I found SQL Dump Task from here http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/carcus88/2011/04/08/sql_dump_task_for_shells

I use in shell.
I already declared

> $tasks = array('SqlDump')

And, I put in these code in the last line of main()

> pr($this->SqlDump->dump_array());

But no sql print out. If anyone know how to use, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

the shell is usually limited in the size of the output (some of it may be cut off in case of too much printout).
therefore I would go with a log solution.

check my component approach:
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/2.0/Controller/Component/CommonComponent.php#L601

it might be re-writable for a shell environment.
basically get the sql log and write it to a file:

```
$log = $object->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
CakeLog::write('sql', $log);
```

of course you could still print it out on the screen, as well.